# how to recognize the face in Group Photo in a website?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have one website implemented by JSP and html.In that, all users will upload their personal photo as their profile picture.Then, one user will upload a group photo.Now, my system has to recognise everyone in that group photo by comparing everyone profile pictures.

Please, anyone tell me how to achieve this task?

Comment: Now is the time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want develop your own logic for face recognize then try with [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) if you want recognize with 3rd party API you can use [Kairos](https://www.kairos.com/)

> **1) [Using OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html#face-recognition)**
>
> 2) Kairos gives developers the best way to add face analysis into their apps. Our Human Analytics platform lets you integrate emotion, identity and demographic data into your products with only a few lines of code.
>
> Through computer vision and machine learning Kairos can recognize and measure people in any video, image or photo.

Comment: I worked with kairos if any help need in Kairos you can ask me.